# HighMaps cannot update options inside mapNavigation field

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I'm trying to enable Mouse Wheel Zoom only when the map is focused. I've made the container div focusable, added relevant click handlers to options for focusing manually (highcharts prevents the default action), and added onfocus and onblur handlers to container div. Inside these handlers I try to update map options to enable mouse wheel zoom.

The problem is, when I update anything inside 'mapNavigation' section, it does not work. I've tried manually update and then check options of a chart, and see this weird behavior.

I guess HighCharts apply a generic option filtering on update function and somehow missed supporting MapNavigation of HighMaps. Or am I doing something wrong, here is my update call:

```
this.chart.update({
    'mapNavigation': {
        'enableMouseWheelZoom': true
    }
});
```

Note: *this* variable is correct, chart is really the chat I'm dealing with. Updating something else (e.g. credits) works.

Comment: It seems that those options are not applied at all. I reported it as a bug [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6369) Until it gets fixed, you can try to destroy and create a new chart with some merged options. http://jsfiddle.net/jee4f12q/1/